# dynamically set currency symbol

Tags: android, textview

In my app there are a lot of textviews which contain a currency symbol.

Now I want the user to set the symbol. I created a sharedpreference and added there all the existing currencies. Unfortunatelly there are approximately 20 different currencies out there.

Therefor I am struggling how to change dynamically the currency symbol in all my textviews.
I could create for each a big switch case statement (with 20 cases) but this will blow up my code extremly.

Is there another technique how I can change the symbol. E.g. with help of an xml file like the different languages...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The efficient way to do this is by using the **[Locale](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html)** and **[Currency](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Currency.html)** classes.

1.Create the Locale object based on the user input

Example:

```
       Locale locale=new Locale("en", "US");
```

2.based on this get the currency symbol and display it.

Example:

```
     Currency currency=Currency.getInstance(locale);
     String symbol = currency.getSymbol();
```

Comment: by using setText() method like textview.setText("some text "+ symbol+" some more text if have");

Comment: this sounds nice! ok but I want the user set the symbol himself. But this should also work with your solution? So not via locale object.

Comment: i think with out using Locale ,it is difficult. why because you need to create the currency symbol explicitly.

Comment: `Locale locale=new Locale("en", "AU");` gives me `AU$` instead of `$`

Answer (score 3):

I think you will need a formatted string from an xml, something like that from [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) :

```
<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
```

Then in your activity :

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages), username, mailCount);
```